# Can I connect two verbs with 'as well as'?

Tags: word-usage

I want to make a sentence like this:

> He has an important role in the system in that he 'verb phrase 1', **as well as** 'verb phrase 2'.

Is the usage of 'as well as' right here?

I think I've seen the use of it just to parallel two nouns or sentences. Here, I want to concentrate on 'verb phrase 1' more than 'verb phrase 2'.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows 'as well as' is generally a gerund form. The other verb is not. He checks accounts as well as controlling IT operations; she sings as well as playing the piano. He had been smoking as well as drinking. The linking phrase can come first - as well as eating a steak, he also drank some beer; as well as running, I will also swim and play tennis.

> As well as running my organics company, I am Ronnie's PA.

[As well as](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-well-as)